# Spring Boot Actuator Audit repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot Actuator project exposes an audit framework. I am trying to use it and while in general it is a quite reasonable implementation I am finding one issue.

`AuditEventRepository` interface has the following method:

`List find(String principal, Date after)`

It is implemented in `InMemoryAuditEventRepository`. The problem is that the second parameter (`Date after`) seems to be ignored.

Am I right?

I am using Spring-Boot-1.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: The `InMemoryAuditEventRepository` only keeps the last 100 events by default and does not retain them on restart obviously so it has probably more limitations than not taking that parameter into account. If that's what you're after, you probably should use an implementation that persists those events.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know all the limitations of `InMemoryAuditEventRepository`. I was going to use my own implementation anyway. However these are limitations while not taking method parameter into account is a bug from my point of view.

Comment: Fair enough. Could you please raise it at github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues - Thanks!

Comment: I did raise an issue [#2291](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2291). Thank you!

Comment: This is already fixed by this: https://github.com/izeye/spring-boot/commit/6ed224c714b9d68cb71bc788b09c716417035735